# Call apsx page from an html page as popup

Tags: html, css, asp.net, iframe, radwindow

I need to Open Code_Page.aspx page in Radwindow as popup.Currently i am able open it ,but now the issue is in .html page that 
the Iframe width is Covering the html page (i.e parent page )  It is opening as default width of iframe , but i need to open as popup.

Here .html page(test.html) is my landing page.I need to assign values to properites(Codebase.MAL.Name,Codebase.MAL.Code) in aspx Page 
before opening popuppage(Code_Page.aspx) Any way that i can achive this .

Comment: Code for Html: test.html
----------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe id="idframe" scrolling="no" src="CoolCode.aspx" frameborder="0" align="middle" ></iframe>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>name</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
----------------------------------------

Comment: Unable to Code hence added as Comment

Comment: Code for Aspx page:CoolCode.aspx
------------------------------------------------
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<script runat="server">
    protected void imgbtncoolpick_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Codebase.MAL.Name = "abc";
        Codebase.MAL.Code = "xyz";
        rwcoolPopUp.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
    }
</script>

Comment: <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Images/coolpic.png" ID="imgbtnHelpDesk" Width="50px" OnClick="imgbtncoolpick_Click" runat="server" />
            <telerik:RadWindow runat="server" ID="rwcoolPopUp" NavigateUrl="Code_Page.aspx" Modal="true" Width="650px" Height="650px" VisibleOnPageLoad="false"></telerik:RadWindow>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
-------------------------------------